# Login system for my C# application

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I have a C# application with a login system it is working fine but what I want is that the user can logout and login again so that the menu in the main form will change its visibility here is how I did it. I have a login form, main form, and an end user class.

the mainform is the first to be run by the program at load it will showdialog the login form.

in the login code. it will pass the username and password to the end user class and check the propery loginsuccess

```
public partial class Login : Form
{
   private void cmdlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsEmpty())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter username/password.");
            TxtFocus();
        }
        else
        {
            EndUser.LogIn(txtusername.Text, txtpassword.Text);
            if (EndUser.LogInSucces)
            {

            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

in the end user class it will open a connection to the database and search if the username and password is available and change the property loginsuccess to true and change the role property to the appropriate one from the enum.

after it the login form will close to show the main form. the main form will check what role is the user and set the visibility of the menus.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
     public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Login loginFrm = new Login();
        loginFrm.ShowDialog();
        this.IsMdiContainer = true;            
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (EndUser.LogInSucces) {
            switch (EndUser.GetRole())
            {
                case EndUser.Role.Principal:
                    PrincipalSettings();
                    break;
                case EndUser.Role.Admission:
                    AdmissionSettings();
                    break;
                case EndUser.Role.Registrar:
                    RegistrarSettings();
                    break;
                case EndUser.Role.Faculty:
                    FacultySettings();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

 #region menus visibility
```

I tried to restart the application by using the command application.restart(), because it will begin to the login flow, but it is not good as when I do something in the program then logout I will get an error. can you give some advice in doing this?

Comment: It seems like you should use a dictionary to find the right method, not `switch`.

Comment: "...I will get an error." Telling us what that error is would be very helpful.